# How to make my python code portable with it’s drivers

Tags: python, linux

I wrote python code on **windows** at development stage, During my project I used many modules for example: pandas,numpy,...etc.
I am trying to deploy this code in production (**Linux**), and those modules not installed on this machine. so I want to make my code portable with it’s drivers and utilities, modules which I used it.
How can I do that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "portable" and "drivers", but might you be looking for [packaging](https://packaging.python.org)? I.e. being able to ``pip install`` your project?

Comment: I just want after writing code in windows, deploy it on Linux, and this machine don’t connected on the internet to download modules which I used it !

Comment: If the target machine is not connected to the internet, it will have a hard time downloading modules, won't it?

Comment: yes, exactly. furthermore I don’t have privileges to do that

Answer (score 0):

1.Generate a requirements.txt file from your local project

2.Login to your linux server via ssh

3.Install the version of python you want on your linux server (it generaly contains  a 2.7 version)

4.Create a specific folder for your project

5.In that folder, create a virtual environment using the Python that you have installed

6. upload the requirements.txt in the folder and install it using `pip install -r requirements.txt` after activating the virtual environment.

Comment: There aren’t internet on the target machine to install modules !!!

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do anything